# WSL2 cannot access forwarded ports

Tags: networking, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, portforwarding

I want to access `127.128.0.11:11224` from WSL2.

I tried forwarding that address and port to localhost and accessing it that way from WSL2, but it doesn't seem to work. It might be related to the way my corporate laptop is set up, but I cannot tell.

I tried forwarding `127.128.0.11:11224` to `127.0.0.1:11224`:

`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 listenport=11224 connectaddress=127.128.0.11 connectport=11224`

But I cannot access it from WSL2:

- `python3.exe -m http.server -b 127.128.0.11 11224` (on Windows)
- `wget localhost:11224` (on Windows - works)
- `wget ${HOST}.local:11224` (in WSL2 - connection times out)

Note that if I run python server directly on `127.0.0.1:11224`, I can access it from WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the [same question](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10206) on GitHub and the answer is that this is by design.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).